# Embedding Youtube Videos on user's wall with the Javascript API

Tags: youtube, facebook-javascript-sdk, embed, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall

I'm attempting to embed a Youtube video on a user's wall using the Javascript API. I've poured over a bunch of different tutorials and came up with this:

```
var data = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: current_video_url, // Link to the vide on our site
    source: current_video_src, // Link to the Youtube video, http://youtube.com/v/[hash]
    picture: current_picture_url, // Thumbnail from youtube
    title: current_video_title, // Title from our page
    caption: current_video_description // Text from our page
}

FB.ui(data);
```

Running the Facebook Debugger shows that the `current_video_url` link is being properly parsed for OG tags and is available as an embedded video. I ran a debugger and all the variables are being properly set in the `data` variable.

This worked fine for about 2 days, and then we pushed the site live. We set up a new AppID in Facebook but now all the videos are just thumbnails instead of being embedded in the user's wall. I thought maybe this is a problem with the live site but now the dev site is broken too.

What's the best way to get this to work consistently?